# How to start Windows Live Mail minimized on Windows 7 on system startup?

Tags: windows, windows-live-mail

How to start Windows Live Mail minimized on Windows 7 on system startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is from startup folder , right click on the shortcut properties->Shortcut->Run 
Change "Normal Window" to "Minimized" . This will start the Live mail minimized.

You could also check where exactly it is running from using [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Add a shortcut to Windows Live Mail to the Startup folder, more info how to accomplish this for Windows 7 can be found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html)